# Is it still possible to develop apps for the App Store with Intellij IDEA 11?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play

I needed to tweak something minor on an old Android application. It was developed ages ago in IntelliJ IDEA v11.  Where as before all I had to do is compile, sign it and submit to the store - this no longer works.

I tried doing it and first it was complaining that I could not submit a debuggable APK.  Now its complaining that it is not Zip Aligned.  I've tried manually aligning it but now it complains that I signed it wrongly.  And so on...

So is it still possible to develop for the Android App Store in IntelliJ IDEA v11?  Or is it easier to simply upgrade to the latest IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Any reason to not update?

Comment: @BrunoR.Cardoso I was hoping for this to be the smallest effort possible.